# appending html to end of JQUERY AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I am trying to do something and after internet research am unclear if I can or not. I would like to add the HTML for a modal at the end of the script, all within the AJAX Success call. Is this possible? Here is the code I have tried:

```js
function options() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'test2_update_function'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#myModal").show(function() {
          // Get the modal
          var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

          // Get the button that opens the modal
          var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

          // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

          // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
          btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
          }

          // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
          span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }

          // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
          window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
        /*>>> closes the .show*/
      ).append('<div id="myModal" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span><p id="my-data"></p></div></div>');
      jQuery("#my-data").html(data); //Add this line
      ;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you really mean something like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").append(`<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p id="my-data"></p>
      </div>
    </div>`); // if you must

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#modal").show()
  })

  $("#modal").on("click", ".close", function() {
    $("#modal").hide();
  })

  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#modal").length === 0 ) {
      $("#modal").hide()
    }
  })
})

function options() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'test2_update_function'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#my-data").html(data); //Add this line
      $("#myModal").show()

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="my-data"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to include the html inside the function so it isnt separate?

Comment: Your append is not appending to anything useful. It looks like you are appending a div with id="myModal" to something with id="myModal"

Comment: I updated to add it onload, but it is not necessary

Comment: Thanks was trying to keep the html in the success function so it was all in one place

Comment: I do not recommend this. They are not truly related. Keep the presentation from the execution